# Сборка проекта OpenGL в g++

Tags: g++, ubuntu, c++, opengl

Короче говоря, я пытаюсь создать openGL приложение (обычное окно с белым квадратом), но даже после установки openGL - ничего. Как добавить OpenGL и как скомпилировать?

**Добавлено.**

```
#include "GL/gl.h"  
#include "GL/glut.h"  

void display(){  
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);  
    glBegin(GL_POINTS);  
    glColor3f(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);  
    glVertex2f(0.25, 0.25);  
    glEnd();    
    glFlush();  
}  

int main(int argc, char** argv){  
    glutInit(&argc, argv);  
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGB);  
    glutInitWindowSize(240, 240);  
    glutInitWindowPosition(100, 740);  
    glutCreateWindow("TEST");  
    glClearColor(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);  
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);  
    glLoadIdentity();  
    glOrtho(0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, -1.0, 1.0);  
    glutDisplayFunc(display);  
    glutMainLoop();  
}
```

> ```
> /tmp/ccQZMEmz.o: In function `main':
> openGL.cpp:(.text+0x65): undefined reference to `glutInit'
> openGL.cpp:(.text+0x6f): undefined reference to `glutInitDisplayMode'
> openGL.cpp:(.text+0x7e): undefined reference to `glutInitWindowSize'
> openGL.cpp:(.text+0x8d): undefined reference to `glutInitWindowPosition'
> openGL.cpp:(.text+0x97): undefined reference to `glutCreateWindow'
> openGL.cpp:(.text+0x102): undefined reference to `glutDisplayFunc'
> openGL.cpp:(.text+0x107): undefined reference to `glutMainLoop'
> collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
> ```

Comment: Mageia release 6 (Official) for x86_64
Чт янв 11 18:52:07 MSK 2018
g++ opengl.cpp -lglut -lGL верно для openGL.cpp Спасибо AlexDenisov
и точно так же верно и для // Урок 34 Anton Te
// Рисуем фрактал Мандельброта

Answer (score 1):

Может сначала надо почитать доки, как создать, а потом пытаться что-то создать?
Определения команд GL находятся в файле gl.h, для включения которого нужно написать

```
#include <gl/gl.h>
```

Для работы с библиотекой GLU нужно аналогично включить файл glu.h.
В отличие от стандартных библиотек, пакет GLUT нужно инсталлировать и подключать отдельно.
Судя по тегу Ubuntu у вас стоит соответствующий дистрибутив, в котором компиляция выполняется командами:

```
qmake -project
qmake Ваш_проект.pro
make
```

При это надо находится в каталоге проекта.

UPD:
Вот достойная (пошаговая) статья [Компилируем в Ubuntu](http://esate.ru/blog/linux/266.html).
Напишите, что именно у вас не получается.

Comment: я конечно подключил glu и glut. вроде-бы как инсталлировал. почему *.pro?

Comment: "Судя по тегу Ubuntu у вас стоит соответствующий дистрибутив, в котором компиляция выполняется командами..." о ужас!!! 

**При чем здесь Qt??? Какая вообще связь между дистрибутивом и проектами Qt???**

Мы даже не знаем какие у человека проблемы, а уже воспитываем и тыкаем в документацию.
В доках зачастую не пишут таких вещей как подключение библиотек

    g++ main.cpp -llibname

полагаю что проблема как раз в этом!

Comment: Уважаемый, @1101_debian
Я предположила, что используется Qt+OpenGL.
Связь простая:
// win + mingw
qmake && mingw32-make
// win + MSVC
qmake && nmake
// linux
qmake && make
"Мы даже не знаем какие у человека проблемы" и именно потому указываем на "документацию" и пошаговое выполнение. Была бы проблема или ошибка - можно было бы решить, остальное гадание на кофейной гуще.

Comment: Вы вынесли мне мозг...

Answer (score 1):

что конкретно не получается? попробуйте так

```
g++ source.cpp -lGL
```

**UPD.**

В общем проблема, как и предполагалось, в линковке. По умолчанию компилятор ищет функции в стандартной библиотеке, но не находит тех которых там нет, потому ему нужно явно указывать в какой библиотеке ему все это искать. Указывается это все при помощи ключа **-l** и имени библиотеки следующим сразу за ключом. К примеру есть у вас где-то библиотека с именем lib**some_library**.so, так вот имя библиотеки здесь выделено жирным.

Также по умолчанию поиск библиотек происходит в пути прописаном в переменной окружения PATH, если же ваша библиотека находится по какому-то "необычному" пути, то этот путь либо нужно добавить в PATH

export PATH=**/some/path/to/library**:$PATH

где жирным выделен путь к библиотеке, либо опять таки указать компилятору явно при помощи ключа **-L**

```
-L/some/path/to/library/
```

В итоге должно выйти что-то вроде

```
g++ main.cpp -L/opt/opengl -lGL
```

Так что посмотрите где лежат ваши библиотеки, как они называются, и вперед ;-)

Answer (score 1):

вот такой командой точно все компилируется

```
g++ openGL.cpp -lglut
```

Comment: на моем дебе чего-то сказало что не находит глат, потому попробовал GL...

Comment: я пробовал под Fedora 15.
glut может не находить - нужно его доустановить.

Comment: я написал в своем ответе с каким именем у меня собралось, так что хз, я вообще не работал с опенгл, года три назад в студенчестве пытался что-то собрать, но под рукой была только книжка, и как сейчас помню была таже проблема что и у вопрощающего, только у меня тогда интернета не было...

Comment: у меня получилось вот так:
g++ opengl.cpp -lglut -lGL

Answer (score 0):

```
$ g++ stackover.cc -o stackover -lGL -lglut -lGLU
$ ls
first3.cc  first.cc  ps-groupgl.cc  stackover  stackover.cc
$ ./stackover
$
```

Это просто.